# Installation of Windows 10 changed UEFI settings

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, ssd, uefi

I've been using Windows 10 and Ubuntu on the same computer from different SSD's, with both systems accessing the same HDD's that are formatted to NTFS. The computer has a Asus z97 motherboard. I just reinstalled Windows, wiping out the old installation, and the following changes occurred in the computer:

1. In the boot device section of the BIOS setup, the motherboard does not offer the SSD with Ubuntu as one of the boot devices that can be chosen as the first, second etc. boot device, although that SSD can be selected as the boot device when the booting is manually interrupted (F8 key).
2. There are 3 HDDs formatted to NTFS, but Windows 10 detects only 2 of them, even though they were all used with Windows without any problems before I reinstalled it.

The Ubuntu OS is a Legacy BIOS installation, and that may have something to do with the boot issue, but something else is causing the failure of Windows to detect all hard drives. After I noticed these problems I restored the default settings in BIOS setup, but it didn't help with the problems.

Comment: It is not possible for the UEFI settings to be chnage by simply installing Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that some of your problems are caused by drivers. Some computers have multiple disk controller chips, each of which may require its own OS driver. If your new installation lacks the right driver, the associated disk(s) will be invisible to the OS. One solution is to install the appropriate driver, which you should be able to find on the motherboard manufacturer's Web site. Another solution is to use the firmware setup utility to switch the disk access mode from "IDE" to "AHCI"; however, this may also require Windows driver changes. (I'm not an expert on Windows drivers, so I can't provide more advice on such a change.) Neither option is entirely risk-free; if the driver is buggy or if you err in installing it, the OS may become unbootable.

As to Ubuntu, if you had been switching between BIOS-mode and EFI-mode booting, that was sub-optimal. I recommend disabling the Compatibility Support Module (CSM) in your firmware, aka "legacy boot support," and installing an EFI boot loader for Linux. Given that you're using Ubuntu, two relatively easy ways to do this are:

- **Boot Repair** -- The [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool can fix many boot problems on Linux systems, especially when the distribution is Debian, Ubuntu, or something related. If you boot an emergency disk *in EFI mode,* this tool will probably be able to install an EFI-mode version of GRUB on the computer, making it bootable again.
- **rEFInd** -- My [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is an EFI-mode boot manager that can boot Linux kernels directly. You can download the USB flash drive or CD-R version, boot from it, and use that to boot into Ubuntu. From there, you can install the EFI-mode version of GRUB or install the rEFInd Debian package or PPA to use rEFInd instead of GRUB to control the boot process.

Note that, especially for the first option, it's necessary that you know how to control your boot mode (BIOS vs. EFI). This is a poorly-understood topic. If you need help, see [my Web page on the CSM.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found answers to the problems I experienced, though I have no answers to what caused them.

When I installed Windows on its SSD, I disconnected all other drives as a precaution against data loss. When the booting problems with Ubuntu arrived, I disconnected all other drives except the Ubuntu drive, and after a few Ubuntu-only startups the booting problem was gone, with all drives connected. A bit like kicking a car that won't start- but it worked.

The HDD problem was caused by inappropriate formatting with Ubuntu's Disk Manager. I formatted it again, choosing "Compatible with modern systems and hard disks", and Windows found it. I may have stumbled in my choice of words- Windows did find the device, but not the volume formatted to it.

I hope my experience with the shared use of a computer by Ubuntu and Windows will be useful to others who encounter similar problems.